# MongoDB: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, illegalstateexception

I have an application that pulls data from one source and then upserts it to MongoDB. Sometimes the pulling process takes a lot of time and when app tries to push a row to MongoDB the following exception is raised probably to the timeout issue:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:492)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:222)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:438)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.receiveMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:262)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandProtocol.execute(UpdateCommandProtocol.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandProtocol.execute(UpdateCommandProtocol.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.updateCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$3.executeWriteCommandProtocol(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:481)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$RunExecutor.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:400)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:180)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:232)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:223)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:827)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:810)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:515)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.update(MongoCollectionImpl.java:508)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:355)
    at com.test.db.mongoDB.RetryingMongoCollection.updateOne(RetryingMongoCollection.java:909)
```

There is a wrapper for MongoCollection class that for each MongoException and now for java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown

```
@Override
public UpdateResult updateOne(Bson filter, Bson update,
        UpdateOptions updateOptions) {
    UpdateResult retVal = null;
    final ExceptionHelper ex = new ExceptionHelper(CAConstants.RETRIES, ErrorType.ERROR, true);
    boolean isDone = false;
    while (!isDone) {
        try {
            retVal = proxied.updateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
            isDone = true;
        } catch (final MongoException | IllegalStateException e) {
            ex.logIfZero("Failed to launch MongoDB operation", e);
            if (ex.lastTry()) {
                isDone = true;
                Log.error("Failed to launch MongoDB operation.", e);
            } else {
                Log.error("[MDB] Going to update mongo instance due to exception", e);
                db = MongoDBFactory.getUpdatedMongoDBInstance();
                setCollection();
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

tries to reload MongoClient:

```
        if ( mongoClient != null ) {
            try {
                mongoClient.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.error("Mongo client throws exception while closing connection", e);
            }
...
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(servers, Arrays.asList(credential), 
                new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                    .requiredReplicaSetName(REPLICASET_NAME)
                    .connectTimeout(0)
                    .connectionsPerHost(CONNECTION_PER_HOST)
                    .cursorFinalizerEnabled(false)
                    .build());

        db = mongoClient.getDatabase(database);
```

However, when the mongoClient is updated after "com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream" it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:827)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:810)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:515)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.update(MongoCollectionImpl.java:508)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:355)
    at com.test.db.mongoDB.RetryingMongoCollection.updateOne(RetryingMongoCollection.java:909)
```

and continues failing all the time...

I use mongoDB ver 3.2.9; 
Mongo java client 3.3.0

Please support.

Comment: I noticed you also posted this question in the mongodb-user group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/hhoFxnSplfI) where Ross asked you to follow-up with a Jira issue. Did you end up filing a report in Jira or finding a solution to your timeout error? When "the pulling process takes a lot of time", how long is that?

Comment: Hi Stennie, the pulling process can take more than an hour. The point is that we pull data from different tables one by one. So, we do not control it...

Answer (score 8):

Try setting maxConnectionIdleTime option in your MongoClientOptions (especially if you are using a hosted MongoDB environment)

Example:

```
    new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
    .requiredReplicaSetName(REPLICASET_NAME)
    .maxConnectionIdleTime (MAX_IDLE_TIME)
    .connectionsPerHost(CONNECTION_PER_HOST)
    .cursorFinalizerEnabled(false)
    .build();
```

connectTimeout is misleading as it is the timeout setting for initial connection.

For the issue around re-initializing the MongoClient, make sure the client code is in the correct scope for the insert code to pick up.  Also, I only see the db and not the collection level object (proxied?) being re-initialized.