# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: state should be: ClientSession from same MongoClient;

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to save Bank details in MongoDB through Spring Boot application. Country code within Bank address gets validated before Bank details are saved into the database. I am getting following error while trying to validate COuntry code:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: state should be: ClientSession from same MongoClient; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: ClientSession from same MongoClient
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.existsById(Unknown Source)
at com.myservice.bankdata.serviceimpl.validateAddresses(ServiceUtility.java:115)
at com.myservice.bankdata.serviceimpl.BankServiceImpl.createEntity(BankServiceImpl.java:83)
at com.myservice.bankdata.serviceimpl.BankServiceImpl.createEntity(BankServiceImpl.java:44)
at com.myservice.bankdata.serviceimpl.BankServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$56da36f8.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
```

My BankServiceImpl looks like:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceUtility serviceUtility;

@Autowired
private BankRepository bankRepo;

@Override
@Transactional
public Bank createEntity(Bank bank) {

    if (null != bank.getAddresses() && !bank.getAddresses().isEmpty()) {
        serviceUtility.validateAddresses(bank.getAddresses());
    }
    Bank savedBank = bankRepo.save(bank);
    return savedBank;
}
```

ServiceUtility:

```
@Autowired
private CountryRepository countryRepo;

public void validateAddresses(List<Address> addresslist) {
    if (primaryAddresses.size()<Constants.PRIMARY_ADDRESS_COUNT)
        throw new ValidationException(MIN_PRIMARY_ADDRESS_COUNT,"");
    for (Address address : addresslist) {
        if (!countryRepo.existsById(address.getCountry().getId()))
            throw new NotFoundException(NO_DATA_FOUND_EXCEPTION, address.getCountry().getId());
    }
}
```

I have checked other resources like [Spring Mongo Support - Exception Translation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html) and [MongoDB: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670865/mongodb-java-lang-illegalstateexception-state-should-be-open), but did not help much.

Would be grateful if you could help me identify possible solution for the same?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage Not yet.

Comment: Are you using the MongoDB Atlas platform or any clustered setup?

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage I have a cluster setup on Azure.